# How to set x button once to clear text and second to close SearchView Android?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, searchview

I have this SearchView:

```
SearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.search);
```

Once I write some text and I press the clear button, the text is cleared and if I press again, the search is closed. If use the following lines of code:

```
ImageView clearButton = searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
clearButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    searchView.setQuery("", false);
});
```

The default behaviour stops working. I set on click listener on the button and it works fine but if I press again, the search is not closing as it happened earlier. How to close the search on second button click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setIconified` to `true` to close the `SearchView`

```
clearButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    if(searchView.getQuery().length() == 0) {
        searchView.setIconified(true);
    } else {
        searchView.setQuery("", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just posted another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730536/unable-to-get-the-text-from-searchview-searchautocomplete-oncreateview-in-fragme). Thanks in advance! Hope you can save me.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!searchView.isIconified()) {
    searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
} else {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```