# Unable to get the text from SearchView.SearchAutoComplete onCreateView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

In my FirstFragment's `onCreateView()` method I have the following elements:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle) {
    initSearchView();
    String selectedItem = search.getText().toString();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView " + selectedItem); //Always empty
}
```

As you can see, I call `initSearchView()` method which looks like this:

```
private void initSearchView() {
    SearchView searchView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.search);
    search = searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    search.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, position, id) -> {
        Item Item = (Item) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        search.setText(item.getItemName()); //Set item name
        goToItemFragment(item.getItemName());
    });
}
```

As you can see, once an item is selected, I set the name of that item to the `search` object. This works fine since I see that the name of the item is placed inside the [search](https://ibb.co/JR6Gtq8).

Here is the method that I use to go to the SecondFragment:

```
private void goToISecondFragment(String itemName) {
    ActionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment action = actionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment();
    action.setItemName(itemName);
    Navigation.findNavController(rootView).navigate(action);
}
```

The problem arrives when I get back from SecondFragment to FirstFragment. Even if I see the selected item name in the [search](https://ibb.co/JR6Gtq8), when the fragment starts, that log statement is always empty, meaning the it doesn't see that text in the search.

How can I get that visible text from search when I get back from SecondFragment to FirstFragment? Thanks

Comment: Where is your SearchView? In Activity or Fragment?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman It is placed in FirstFragment's .XML file.

Comment: `SearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.search);` Then how could you get this without view? ``. That's why i said you to post full fragment code

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I'm sorry, my mistake. It is `rootView.findViewById(R.id.search)`. Just updated my question. Please take a look.

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman So you think that is a way to solve this? Thanks